# How to align html elements horizontally when they have different parents

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a basic html document with a sticky header and footer.  I also have a div below the header that sticks to the header because it will eventually contain some tabs above a form.  I have tried to align the form below this vertically but they don't line up.  The problem is the tab div does not have a scrollbar but the form does.  This means the width of the form is different to the width of the tabs. I tried to set them to 70% of the width and center but, because of the scrollbar they don't line up.  I've tried some javascript to get the width of the scrollbar and then add this to the current right margin but it doesn't work. You will see the form is not as wide as the tabs div. I have spent hours on this.
Also, I tried adding a margin-bottom to the form but no margin appears below the border.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  setFormsWidth();
});

function setFormsWidth() {
   
  let scrollbox = document.createElement('div');

  // Make box scrollable
  scrollbox.style.overflow = 'scroll';

  // Append box to document
  document.body.appendChild(scrollbox);

  // Measure inner width of box
  scrollBarWidth = scrollbox.offsetWidth - scrollbox.clientWidth;
  

  // Remove box
  document.body.removeChild(scrollbox);

  // Get current width of right margin, which should be 30% of the
  // width of the form-panel parent (the content class). 
  var formPanel = document.getElementById("main-form");

  // Get the current right margin and remove the px at end of number
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(formPanel);
  var marginRightString = style.getPropertyValue('margin-right');
  var marginRight = marginRightString.slice(0,-2);

  // now addthe scrollBarWidth to the right margin
  var newMargin = marginRight + scrollBarWidth;

  formPanel.style.marginRight = newMargin + "px";

}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header, .footer {
  background: silver;
}
.page {
  flex: 1;
   overflow: auto; 
   background: pink;
}

.content {
  background-color: green;;
}

.tabs {
  width: 70%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: solid #FE6D73 7px; 
}

.form-panel {
  width: 70%; 
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-bottom: solid #FE6D73 7px; 

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="tabs">
      THIS IS TAB
    </div>
    <div class="page" id="calculator">
      <div style="height:1000px;">
        <div class="content">
       
          <form class="form-panel" id="main-form">THIS IS FORM</form>
            
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve can you explain it in simpler way so i can help you?

Comment: The form (white) and the tab div (blue) are the same width on my computer.

Comment: That's very strange.  I did notice they can look the same on a my mobile because it isn't showing the scrollbar but they definitely are not the same on my desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to show the scrollbar besides `.form-panel` element but not `.page` div, so it will not affect centering `.form-panel` element.

Here is how to change the css.

- Set height to 100% for all elements between `.page` and `.form-panel` elements, including `.form-panel` itself, so that scrollbar for `.page` will not be shown
- Set `box-sizing: border-box;` for `.form-panel`, so that the border is drawn inside `.form-panel`
- move `.footer` outside `.page` element

If you would like to set a specific height for `.form-panel`, you can create a div inside it and set its height like below:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header, .footer {
  background: silver;
}
.page {
  flex: 1;
   overflow: auto; 
   background: pink;
}

.content {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
}

.tabs {
  width: 70%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: solid #FE6D73 7px; 
}

.form-panel {
  width: 70%; 
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-bottom: solid #FE6D73 7px; 
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="tabs">
      THIS IS TAB
    </div>
    <div class="page" id="calculator">
      <div style="height:100%;">
        <div class="content">
       
          <form class="form-panel" id="main-form">
            <div style="height:1000px">
              THIS IS FORM
            </div>
          </form>
            
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  I will try your idea tomorrow.  I am in Western Australia and we are at the end of the day here.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort.  Your solution works well.  Exactly what I needed.  I am still finding my way around css, having been used to java for many years and finding css is so much more tedious to code.  But getting there.

Comment: You're welcome. There are so much variation in CSS, and I think it is a very powerful language. I am also still on my way learning CSS, I have learnt a lot from Stackoverflow too. If you find my answer helpful, feel free to mark it as accepted answer